# How to insert array into associate array with a random order in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

**I have an associate array with a bunch of arrays inside *already***.

**I don't want to change the existing items' relative order(arrays already in the associative array)**, but, I'd like to insert ***new*** arrays into it with a random order(in between of the existing items). I tried multiple ways but none of them worked.

P.S.: I wrote a function which can insert array into associate array, but it always add array to the end of the associative array.

```
protected function array_push_assoc(&$array, $key, $value){
    $array[$key] = $value;
    return $array;
}
```

---

For example:

Original

```
array(
     'apple'=>50,
     'pear'=>10,
     'banana'=>20
);
```

After:

```
array(
     'apple'=>50,   //<=== This remains the same relative order to pear and banana
     'pear'=>10,    //<=== This remains the same relative order to apple and banana
     'something'=>15,    //<===== this is randomly put in here.
     'banana'=>20  //<=== This remains the same relative order to apple and pear
);
```

Comment: shuffle() it after adding ?

Comment: @Dagon I don't want to mess up the original items' order tho.

Comment: You want to `"insert new arrays into it with a random order"` but you `"I don't want to mess up the original items' order tho"`?

Comment: @Darren The original associative array contains a bunch of arrays already.

Comment: post example of array before and after, we are confused

Comment: @jackhao Please do as Dagon just said.

Comment: @Darren Already did. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK in case anyone faces the same problem in the future, here is the solution:

```
            $random = rand(0, count($array) - 1);
            $array = array_slice($array, 0, $random, true) + array($key => $value) + array_slice($array, $random, count($array) - 1, true);
```

This will get the job done.